# Background image is not 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a picture as Background.

But Background image is not 100% width. There is a blank on the right side.

Does anyone can help me please?

Comment: Nope, please provide a small reproducible demo right there.

Comment: Sure. But what do you mean by a demo of website inside this stackotherflow page: screenshot? Video? Source code?

Comment: A piece of code enough to reproduce the problem. Not all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style update to the background image container:

```
.row-feature:first-child {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Make sure to add this styling under the background image declaration.